# how to access SimpleChildWindow from other UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two user controls in wpf and i have defined simple child window in both of them now i want to access them in the way like Uc1 have child1 and Uc2 have child2 i want to access child2 from Uc1 and vice versa from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do that is, via the mainwindow. You don't want to create dependencies between both the controls. This is because of reusing the usercontrols.

This is an example passing the childs thru an event. I wouldn't pass the mainwindow as a reference into the UserControl's constructor.

*If you want to do that, you should create an interface and implement it on the MainWindow and pass it as an interface.*

like:

**UC1**`-(event)>`**MainWindow**`-(methodcall)>`**UC2**`-(methodcall)>`**UC2.child**

---

*Pseudo code:*

```
// event args.
public class RequestChildEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Child2 Child { get;set; }
}

public class UC1
{
    // do something when you need the child2
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var child2 = GetChild2();
        if(child2 == null)
            // cry.
    }

    // this method requests a reference of child2
    private Child2 GetChild2()
    {
        // check if the event is assigned.
        if(RequestChild == null)
            return null;

        RequestChildEventArgs args = new RequestChildEventArgs();
        RequestChild2(this, args);
        return args.Child;
    }

    public event EventHandler<RequestChildEventArgs> RequestChild2;
}

// user control 2
public class UC2
{
    public Child2 Child2 { get; } = new Child2();
}

// the mainwindow that tunnels the Child2
public class MainWindow
{
    private UC1 _uc1;
    private UC2 _uc2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _uc1 = new UC1();
        _uc2 = new UC2();

        _uc1.RequestChild2 += (s, e) => e.Child = _uc2.Child2;
    }
}
```

---

**the visa versa version:**

*Pseudo code:*

```
// event args.
public class RequestChildEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Child { get; set; }
}

public class UC1
{
    public Child1 Child1 { get; } = new Child1();

    // do something when you need the child2
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var child2 = GetChild2();
        if (child2 == null)
            // cry.
    }

    // this method requests a reference of child2
    private Child2 GetChild2()
    {
        // check if the event is assigned.
        if(RequestChild2 == null)
            return null;

        RequestChildEventArgs<Child2> args = new RequestChildEventArgs<Child2>();
        RequestChild2(this, args);
        return args.Child;
    }

    public event EventHandler<RequestChildEventArgs<Child2>> RequestChild2;
}

// user control 2
public class UC2
{
    public Child2 Child2 { get; } = new Child2();

    // do something when you need the child1
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var child1 = GetChild1();
        if(child1 == null)
            // cry.
    }

    // this method requests a reference of child1
    private Child1 GetChild1()
    {
        // check if the event is assigned.
        if(RequestChild1 == null)
            return null;

        RequestChildEventArgs<Child1> args = new RequestChildEventArgs<Child1>();
        RequestChild1(this, args);
        return args.Child;
    }

    public event EventHandler<RequestChildEventArgs<Child1>> RequestChild1;
}

// the mainwindow that tunnels the Childs
public class MainWindow
{
    private UC1 _uc1;
    private UC2 _uc2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _uc1 = new UC1();
        _uc2 = new UC2();

        _uc1.RequestChild2 += (s, e) => e.Child = _uc2.Child2;
        _uc2.RequestChild1 += (s, e) => e.Child = _uc1.Child1;
    }
}
```

This way is you usercontrol **not** dependend on the mainwindow or singleton objects.

Comment: can u please post the code here ? it would be really helpful for me !